# Is it possible to explain geometrically why $\tan^2\alpha_T + \tan^2\beta_T =$const.?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

Recently I have found an old journal of Serbian Mathematical Society, and there is one neat award task for high school students.

> A circle $k$ is inscribed in a square $ABCD$. For an arbitrary point $T$ of circle $k$ let $\alpha_T$ and $\beta_T$ are angles under which diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ can be seen. Prove that for each $T \in k$ it holds $\, \tan^2\alpha_T + \tan^2\beta_T =8$.

The proof that was proposed sets up a square in the coordinate system such that $A=(-a, -a), B=(a,-a), C=(a,a)$ and $D=(-a,a)$. Then for coordinates of an arbitrary point $T(x,y)$ at a circle $k$ which is inscribed in a square $ABCD$ will hold $x^2+y^2 = a^2$.

Next steps yielded the vectors $\vec{TA}=\{-a-x,-a-y\}, \vec{TB}=\{a-x,-a-y\}$, $\vec{TC}=\{a-x,a-y\}$ and $\vec{TD}=\{-a-x,a-y\}$. Now, it can easily be seen that we have:
$$
\cos^2\alpha_T=\frac{a^2}{5a^2-8xy} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \cos^2\beta_T=\frac{a^2}{5a^2+8xy}.
$$

Finally, we will have:
$$
\tan^2\alpha_T+\tan^2\beta_T=\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha_T}+\frac{1}{\cos^2\beta_T}-2=\frac{5a^2-8xy}{a^2}+\frac{5a^2+8xy}{a^2}-2=\boxed{8}.
$$

**Q**: Can someone elaborate this neat award task for high school students with a geometric explanation? Thanks for reading.

**Figure**
[image]

Comment: To @user10354138: Thanks for answering. Next, do we agree: $X$ is intersection of the line $AT$ and the line perpendicular on it which passes point $C$? Similar, $Y$ is intersection of the line $BT$ and the line perpendicular on it which passes point $C$??

Comment: Ok, I used GeoGebra for help. I got $CT^2/XT^2+CT^2/YT^2 \neq const$.

Comment: Oops, made a mistake in identifying $\beta_T$.  Need to find a simultaneous $\alpha_T$ and $\beta_T$ angle...  Doesn't look like there is a way to put them all in the same circle.

Comment: Same sort of idea, but this time it should work: rotate by 90 degrees to get a $T'$ on $k$ and drop perpendiculars from $D$ onto $BT$, $BT'$ with feet $F,F'$ respectively.  Then $-\tan\alpha_T=DF'/F'T'$ and $-\tan\beta_T=DF/FT$.  Now if you know distance of $T$ from the sides of square (and $AB$ too if not assume unit length) then $\tan\angle TBC=t$ then you know $\angle TBD=45^\circ-\angle TBC$ and hence $\tan\angle TBD=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$ hence $DF/AB$, $FT/AB$ and $DF'/F'T'$.  Similar calculation gives $DF'/F'T'$.